# Firebase-database structure efficiency vs. flatness

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The basic flow of my app is a user send out a post to their friends and the friends can post responses to that post and everyone the initial post was sent to can see everyones responses.

I've got 2 options I feel like :

```
1)
users
  9308490384
     postsInitiated
         029309jf: true
     InitiationsInvitedTo
         lsfjijl39j390jf: true
         lkajls;dkfj3ijl3f: true
initiations: 
   029309jf
      timestamp: 293084093
      picURL: picture.com
      replies:
           abc123: true
           edf234: true
   lsfjijl39j390jf
       etc..
replies: 
   abc123         
      picURL: picture.com
      posterUID: lsjdflkjk
```

2)

```
users
  9308490384
     postsInitiated
         029309jf: true
     InitiationsInvitedTo
         lsfjijl39j390jf: true
         lkajls;dkfj3ijl3f: true
initiations: 
   029309jf
      timestamp: 293084093
      picURL: picture.com
      replies:
         abc123         
             picURL: picture.com
             posterUID: lsjdflkjk
```

The difference between the two is under initiations under "replies". The 1st option has a list of replies like

```
abc123: true
```

and then I'd use the abc123 key to search through the replies bit to find the picURL/posterUID.

The second option just lists the reply data right in the Initiation's replies bit.

I see a lot of chat apps that have a user-messages node and then an "all messages" array and you use the UIDS of the messages from the user-messages node to go search through the all messages node.

Is there any potential problem with just listing the reply information under the Initiations in this case? I could definitely flatten it out more by pointing to a "replies" node, but this seems unnecessary.  I dont see the need to flatten that much, but nearly everywhere I see it recommended that you flatten your data as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of approach 1 is that you'll only have to write data in one place. So it simplifies your code that writes the data. It also reduces the amount of data duplication to just the keys.

The advantage of approach 2 is that you'll have to load data only from one location in the tree. So it simplifies your code that reads data. It also has a tiny performance benefit, but that should not be the reason to pick that model.

There is not specific best solution (to be honest: there hardly every is). It all depends on your app and its use-cases. Since you're likely to uncover the use-cases as you are building your app (and as your users start working with it), either approach is likely well enough to get started with.